# Throwing two NullPointerExceptions in a toString method

Tags: java, exception, throw

How do I throw two `NullPointerException`s in the same method?
This is what I've got right now, but the second throw is causing an error "unreachable statement"

```
public String toString() {
    if (rank == null || suit == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException ("Rank cannot be null");
        throw new NullPointerException ("Suit cannot be null");
    }
    return rank + suit;
}
```

Comment: You can't throw two exceptions at once. Instead, you should check for each condition separately.

Comment: a toString implementation should return a string representation of an object in a determinate internal state, i think you shouldn't throw an exception in a kind of method like this one.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot throw more than one exception at a time. Moreover, you should not throw an exception from a method like `toString()` (instead, throw an exception when the object is created if it is invalidly constructed). For something like this, just throw an exception for the first error encountered.

A better way to structure this code would be:

```
 public class Card {
    private final Rank rank;
    private final Suit suit;

    public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
       this.rank = Preconditions.checkNotNull(rank);
       this.suit = Preconditions.checkNotNull(suit);
    }

    public String toString() {
      return "Card(rank=" + rank + ",suit=" + suit + ")";
    }
 }
```

Here, I'm assuming you use [Preconditions](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html).[checkNotNull()](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkNotNull(T)) from the Guava library to simplify the check.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that (think about what your receiving end would have to look like!), but you can say:

```
if (rank == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Rank cannot be null");
if (suit == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Suit cannot be null");
```

(Notice my use of IllegalArgumentException instead of NullPointerException - the IllegalArgumentException is more in line with what you're hoping to achieve. You'd expect a NullPointerException if you're trying to call a method on `rank` or `suit`, not when you're knowingly checking its value).

Or, you can subclass an exception:

```
public class RankException extends IllegalArgumentException
```

Then in your try-catch block, you can do:

```
try {
  s = toString();
} catch (RankException e) {
  // do something with e
} catch (SuitException e) {
  // do something with e
}
```

Comment: Actually, NullPointerException is arguably the right type to use if an argument is invalid for being a null pointer.

Comment: Be careful you don't go down a rabbit hole subclassing exceptions; it's easy to get over-specific, or draw lines in the wrong places. You generally want to think about how you're going to *recover* from the exception when deciding how to structure an exception hierarchy (e.g. is it significant that `rank` was `null` vs. `suit` being `null`?).

Answer (score 1):

You can't throw two exceptions one after the other. As soon as one is reached, the program will throw the exception up until it is either caught in a try catch or it reaches the JVM.
If you want to have different messages for different scenarios...

```
public String toString() {
    if(rank == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Rank cannot be null");
    }
    if(suit == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Suit cannot be null");
    }
    return rank+suit;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `throw` an exception, it leaves your method immediately (unless you catch it later in the same method).  If you really want to put both pieces of information in the message, you could do something like this:

```
public String toString() {
    if (rank == null || suit == null) {
        String message = "";
        if (rank == null)
            message = "Rank cannot be null";
        if (suit == null) {
            if (!message.isEmpty())
                message += ", ";
            message += "Suit cannot be null";
        }
        //throw new NullPointerException(message);
        throw new RuntimeException(message);  // this really isn't a NullPointerException
    }
    return rank + suit;
}
```

(P.S. I agree with Michael that `toString` shouldn't be checking for this.  If this condition is invalid, it should be caught in a constructor or in other methods that could set `rank` or `suit`.)

Comment: These really aren't NullPointerExceptions, though.

Comment: That seems a little overly complex; but I guess if you *really* want specific error messages...

Answer (score 0):

You can't throw two exceptions at once. What would you catch? The second one is unreachable code because throwing an exception leaves the function.

Either check for the conditions separately:

```
if (rank == null)
    throw new NullPointerException ("Rank cannot be null");
if (suit == null)
    throw new NullPointerException ("Suit cannot be null");
```

Or combine them:

```
if (rank == null || suit == null)
    throw new NullPointerException ("Rank or suit cannot be null");
```

Or include the info in the string (you don't generally want to be throwing exceptions from `toString()` anyways:

```
return (rank == null ? "?" : rank) + (suit == null ? "?" : suit);
```

Or more clearly specify class invariants and ensure that `rank` and `suit` are never `null` (e.g. check in the constructor, and validate if `rank` and `suit` have setters).